# Zend Framework 2 | instance of Type

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm wondering why i get different results while checking this:

The ouput of this:

```
get_class($request);
```

"Zend\Console\Request"

First example (output is true):

```
    use Zend\Console\Request as ConsoleRequest,

    class Module {
        public function test() {

          var_dump($request instanceof ConsoleRequest);
        }
    }
```

Second Example (output is false):

```
    class Module {
        public function test() {

          var_dump($request instanceof Zend\Console\Request);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, try with the fully qualified class name:

```
class Module {
    public function test() {

      var_dump($request instanceof \Zend\Console\Request);
    }
}
```

Otherwise PHP tries to look into a subnamespace called Zend into your current namespace.